# Safari flex-grow behavior different from Chrome/FF/Edge (css flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm getting different behavior between Safari and Chrome/FF/Edge using `flex-grow`. I'm trying to get a vertical center, but safari is giving more of a fixed to bottom effect.

I'm using `flex-grow` with a decimal, but Safari seems to interpret it as a whole value.

HTML

```
<div class="fc">
  <div>Align Top</div>
  <div>Align Center</div>
  <div>Align Bottom</div>
  <div class="spacer">Bottom Spacer</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fc { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkBlue;
  color: gold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.fc div {
  outline: 2px dashed gold;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fc div:first-child {
  outline: 1px dashed salmon;
  padding: 15px;
  flex-grow: .5;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/dmgig/pen/NvMKJW

Problem behavior on Safari 10 (10.12)

[image: Safari 10 on 10.2]

Desired behavior on other browsers

[image: All other browsers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a bug report here: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/182

It suggests just using a percentage height on the element and removing flex-grow altogether, which does indeed work well for the purpose.

```
.fc div:first-child {
  outline: 1px dashed salmon;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 25%;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make the body a flex container, set the `fc` to `flex-grow: 1` (and remove `height: 100%`) it will render as you want

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEJbOz)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fc { 
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkBlue;
  color: gold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.fc div {
  outline: 2px dashed gold;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fc div:first-child {
  outline: 1px dashed salmon;
  padding: 15px;
  flex-grow: .5;
  opacity: .5;
}

.fc div.spacer {
  outline: 1px dashed salmon;
  padding: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .5;
  padding: 15px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: salmon;
  color: darkBlue;
  opacity: .5;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="fc">
  <div>Align Top</div>
  <div>Align Center</div>
  <div>Align Bottom</div>
  <div class="spacer">Bottom Spacer</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

---

You can also remove the `position: fixed` on the `footer` and make it all more responsive

[Updated codepen 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayGbeM)

Comment: Thanks for these. It seems like, for #1, it still has different behavior on Safari vs the others and Safari the same issue - the "align center" & "align bottom" divs remain fixed near the bottom no matter how large the window expands. #2 seems to exhibit similar behavior as #1, except for it gives more space on the bottom. I think i may not have made the "vertical center" ideal clear.

Comment: @dgig Okay, don't have Safari and can't test myself. So what you say is this didn't make any difference? ... if so, then I delete this answer

Comment: No it definitely made a difference, just not exactly what I needed. I would leave it for people to see. Thank you for your help.